# Can I omit verb, preposition.... altogether in a parallel structure?

Tags: parallelism

> In the light of this statement, teachers live by selling knowledge, philosophers by selling wisdom, and priests by selling spiritual comfort.

In this parallel structure, can I rewrite it into

> ... teachers live by selling knowledge, philosophers wisdom, and priests
> spiritual comfort.

If it is ok, could you tell me the general rule for such omission?

Comment: Yes, it is OK in my opinion. I would say as long as the context makes it unambiguous, it would be OK to make such structures!!! I am not a native speaker of English though.

Comment: I find it a bit awkward so I would avoid it in that particular example.

Comment: This sentence is crying out for an Oxford comma

Comment: @Ben Jackson Thanks, I've added the comma.

Comment: correction: in light of, no the.

Comment: with "the" is the British version, please check out this [link] (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-the-light-of-sth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version is correct, but taut. It takes a little while to parse. I can imagine a context where you might want the reader to pause to think about it.

The long version flows smoothly.

There is no general rule to apply when choosing between them. Which is better depends on how you want your reader to respond.

(I think @BenJackson is right about the comma.)